# So I am running an ESP32 and i currently have it set to implement 2 tasks. Core 0 is aborting due to the watch dog timer

Tags: timertask, esp32, watchdog

Task1 running on core 0
Task2 running on core 1
The response from slave 1 data register 40007 failed!
The response from slave 1 data register 40008 failed!
The response from slave 1 data register 40020 failed!
The response from slave 1 data register 40021 failed!
E (13183) task_wdt: Task watchdog got triggered. The following tasks did not reset the watchdog in time:
E (13183) task_wdt:  - IDLE0 (CPU 0)
E (13183) task_wdt: Tasks currently running:
E (13183) task_wdt: CPU 0: Task1
E (13183) task_wdt: CPU 1: loopTask
E (13183) task_wdt: Aborting.
abort() was called at PC 0x400d606b on core 0

Backtrace: 0x40090bbc:0x3ffbe190 0x40090ded:0x3ffbe1b0 0x400d606b:0x3ffbe1d0 0x40084af5:0x3ffbe1f0 0x400d1585:0x3ffc79b0 0x400d19ef:0x3ffc79d0 0x400d1e85:0x3ffc79f0 0x400d2996:0x3ffc7a10 0x4008d6b9:0x3ffc7a30

Rebooting...

Comment: Is there a way I can go into the hardware program of the ESP32 and change the wdt time?

Comment: The watchdog timers serve an important purpose. Much better to fix your code. Describing it is not helpful when you're seeking help. Sharing a minimal, viable, complete program that demonstrates the problem means you're more likely to actually get help or a solution and not just downvoted.

Comment: Will sharing the code help more?

Answer (score 0):

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(MAX485_RE_NEG, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(MAX485_DE, OUTPUT);
  // Init in receive mode
  digitalWrite(MAX485_RE_NEG, 0);
  digitalWrite(MAX485_DE, 0);

  // Modbus communication runs at 9600 baud
  Serial2.begin(9600);

  // Modbus slave ID 1
  node.begin(1, Serial2);
  // Callbacks allow us to configure the RS485 transceiver correctly
  node.preTransmission(preTransmission);
  node.postTransmission(postTransmission);
 
  Serial.begin(38400);
  while (!Serial);   //while not serial Wait...
  delay(1500);
  Serial.println("Program has Started");


  for(int i=0; i<InArraySize; i++){
    pinMode(iPins[i],INPUT_PULLUP);                                                   //To enable PULL-UP resistors change "INPUT" with "INPUT_PULLUP"
  }
  for(int i=0; i<OutArraySize; i++){
    pinMode(oPins[i],OUTPUT);
  }
  //interrupt-tag
  // start the Modbus RTU client


  initTCC();


  //rtc1-tag

  digitalWrite(13, HIGH);


xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
      Task1code, /* Function to implement the task */
      "Task1", /* Name of the task */
      10000,  /* Stack size in words */
      NULL,  /* Task input parameter */
      0,  /* Priority of the task */
      &Task1,  /* Task handle. */
      0); /* Core where the task should run */

 xTaskCreatePinnedToCore(
       Task2code,   /* Task function. */
       "Task2",     /* name of task. */
       10000,       /* Stack size of task */
       NULL,        /* parameter of the task */
       1,           /* priority of the task */
       &Task2,      /* Task handle to keep track of created task */
       1);          /* Core where the task should run */

/**************************************Bluetooth*****************************************/
  /*Serial.begin(115200);
  SerialBT.begin("ESP32test"); //Bluetooth device name
  Serial.println("The device started, now you can pair it with bluetooth!");
  */
  
 // esp_task_wdt_init(7, true);  //watchdog
 // esp_task_wdt_add(Task1);     //watchdog

}


void Task1code( void * pvParameter) 
{
  Serial.print("Task1 running on core ");
  Serial.println(xPortGetCoreID());
  
  for(;;) 
  {
    mainRoutine();
    updateRegisters();
   
  }
// esp_task_wdt_reset();   //watchdog
}



void Task2code( void * pvParameter) 
{
  Serial.print("Task2 running on core ");
  Serial.println(xPortGetCoreID());
  for(;;) 
  {
    /**************************************Bluetooth*****************************************/
  /*if (Serial.available()) 
  {
    SerialBT.write(Serial.read());
  }
  if (SerialBT.available()) 
  {
    Serial.write(SerialBT.read());
  }
  delay(20);
  */

  
  if ((millis()-pollTemp)>pollInterval){
    pollDone=true;
//using mod move (unit id ,place to store data, data target address)
//using mod move (unit id, place to store data, data target address, min value, max value)  
  nFile[0]=(int16_t)modMove(0x06); //hz xx.x
  mainRoutine();
  updateRegisters();
  nFile[7]=(int16_t)modMove(0x07); //Amps xx.x
  mainRoutine();
  updateRegisters();
  nFile[2]=(int16_t)modMoveScaled(0x13, 0, 1000); //Analog value 1 (0-1000=(0-1000) for a percentage
  mainRoutine();
  updateRegisters();
  nFile[3]=(int16_t)modMoveScaled(0x14, 0, 1000); //Analog value 2 (200-1000)=(0-1000) for a percentage
  mainRoutine();
  updateRegisters();
  nFile[8]=(int16_t)modMove(0x16); //DC Bus Voltage
  mainRoutine();
  updateRegisters();
  nFile[6]=(int16_t)modMove(0xAC); //Motor Rated Current xx.x
    } else {
    pollDone=false;
  }
  if (pollDone){
    pollTemp=millis();
  }
    if ((millis()-pollTemp2)>pollInterval2){
    pollDone2=true;
  Serial.print("The current setpoint setpoint is: ");
  Serial.println(nFile[2]);
  Serial.print("The current wakeup point setpoint is: ");
  Serial.println(nFile[4]);
  Serial.print("PSI at setpoint: ");
  Serial.println(getBitWord(2, 0, 0));
  Serial.print("PSI at wakeup point: ");
  Serial.println(getBitWord(2, 0, 1));
  Serial.print("Start sleep timer: ");
  Serial.println(getBitWord(2, 0, 2));
  Serial.print("Hz at 60: ");
  Serial.println(getBitWord(2, 0, 3));
  Serial.print("Torque <= 46%: ");
  Serial.println(getBitWord(2, 0, 4));
  Serial.print("Start fault1 timer: ");
  Serial.println(getBitWord(2, 0, 5));
  Serial.print("Drive Running: ");
  Serial.println(getBitWord(2, 0, 7));
  Serial.print("Comm Fault: ");
  Serial.println(getBitWord(2, 1, 0));
  Serial.print("Underload fault: ");
  Serial.println(getBitWord(2, 1, 1));
  Serial.print("current reset state: ");
  Serial.println(!getBitWord(0, 0, 1));
  Serial.print("Flosting point torque= ");
  Serial.println(fFile[2]);
    } else {
    pollDone2=false;
  }
  if (pollDone2){
    pollTemp2=millis();
  }

  }
}
```

Comment: This is the code that we have plus a ton of functions and initializations that I didn't want to post.

Comment: I can't be sure without seeing more code, but you might add a call to vTaskDelay() inside your forever loop in Task1code. It appears to be running full throttle right now.

Comment: That's exaclty what I needed, I solved the issue by just adding a 1 ms delay in my first loop. That was it! Thank you!